# Rodar nhibernate no macOS X 10.13.3 (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, osx, mac

Bom dia, sou novo no mundo de programação C# e portanto tive alguns problemas ao compilar um projeto pelo **visual studio for mac**. O problema foi o seguinte, o projeto utiliza a versão 4.0.3 do **nHibernate** para fazer a persistência do banco, e ao compilar exibe o seguinte erro para mim:

```
    Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'mweb.bot.Program' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic) [0x00003] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:192 
  at NHibernate.AdoNet.SqlClientSqlCommandSet..ctor () [0x00006] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at NHibernate.AdoNet.SqlClientBatchingBatcher.CreateConfiguredBatch () [0x00000] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at NHibernate.AdoNet.SqlClientBatchingBatcher..ctor (NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager connectionManager, NHibernate.IInterceptor interceptor) [0x00034] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at NHibernate.AdoNet.SqlClientBatchingBatcherFactory.CreateBatcher (NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager connectionManager, NHibernate.IInterceptor interceptor) [0x00000] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager..ctor (NHibernate.Engine.ISessionImplementor session, System.Data.IDbConnection suppliedConnection, NHibernate.ConnectionReleaseMode connectionReleaseMode, NHibernate.IInterceptor interceptor) [0x00034] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl..ctor (System.Data.IDbConnection connection, NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl factory, System.Boolean autoclose, System.Int64 timestamp, NHibernate.IInterceptor interceptor, NHibernate.EntityMode entityMode, System.Boolean flushBeforeCompletionEnabled, System.Boolean autoCloseSessionEnabled, System.Boolean ignoreExceptionBeforeTransactionCompletion, NHibernate.ConnectionReleaseMode connectionReleaseMode) [0x000aa] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.OpenSession (System.Data.IDbConnection connection, System.Boolean autoClose, System.Int64 timestamp, NHibernate.IInterceptor sessionLocalInterceptor) [0x00049] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.OpenSession (NHibernate.IInterceptor sessionLocalInterceptor) [0x0001f] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.OpenSession () [0x00000] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at mweb.dao.ContextoHQL`1[T].ObterSessao () [0x0001d] in /Users/gaignoux/Documents/GitHub/MWeb/mweb.dao/ContextoHQL.cs:65 
  at mweb.dao.EmpresaDAO..ctor () [0x00000] in Users/gaignoux/Documents/GitHub/MWeb/mweb.dao/EmpresaDAO.cs:12 
  at mweb.bot.Program..cctor () [0x00010] in /Users/gaignoux/Documents/GitHub/MWeb/mweb.bot/Program.cs:23 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'mweb.bot.Program' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic) [0x00003] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:192 
  at NHibernate.AdoNet.SqlClientSqlCommandSet..ctor () [0x00006] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at NHibernate.AdoNet.SqlClientBatchingBatcher.CreateConfiguredBatch () [0x00000] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at NHibernate.AdoNet.SqlClientBatchingBatcher..ctor (NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager connectionManager, NHibernate.IInterceptor interceptor) [0x00034] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at NHibernate.AdoNet.SqlClientBatchingBatcherFactory.CreateBatcher (NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager connectionManager, NHibernate.IInterceptor interceptor) [0x00000] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager..ctor (NHibernate.Engine.ISessionImplementor session, System.Data.IDbConnection suppliedConnection, NHibernate.ConnectionReleaseMode connectionReleaseMode, NHibernate.IInterceptor interceptor) [0x00034] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl..ctor (System.Data.IDbConnection connection, NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl factory, System.Boolean autoclose, System.Int64 timestamp, NHibernate.IInterceptor interceptor, NHibernate.EntityMode entityMode, System.Boolean flushBeforeCompletionEnabled, System.Boolean autoCloseSessionEnabled, System.Boolean ignoreExceptionBeforeTransactionCompletion, NHibernate.ConnectionReleaseMode connectionReleaseMode) [0x000aa] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.OpenSession (System.Data.IDbConnection connection, System.Boolean autoClose, System.Int64 timestamp, NHibernate.IInterceptor sessionLocalInterceptor) [0x00049] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.OpenSession (NHibernate.IInterceptor sessionLocalInterceptor) [0x0001f] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.OpenSession () [0x00000] in <d1bed2f218f24e45a019c5c80a004c83>:0 
  at mweb.dao.ContextoHQL`1[T].ObterSessao () [0x0001d] in /Users/gaignoux/Documents/GitHub/MWeb/mweb.dao/ContextoHQL.cs:65 
  at mweb.dao.EmpresaDAO..ctor () [0x00000] in /Users/gaignoux/Documents/GitHub/MWeb/mweb.dao/EmpresaDAO.cs:12 
  at mweb.bot.Program..cctor () [0x00010] in /Users/gaignoux/Documents/GitHub/MWeb/mweb.bot/Program.cs:23 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Alguém ja teve um problema desse?

Comment: "o parâmetro `type` não pode ser nulo"

Comment: Consegui resolver agorinha, a partir deste topico aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439946/error-500-while-running-a-fluent-nhibernate-project-with-visual-studio-2015-for